# My programs use Entity Framework. How can I add a field to a database table without having them throw exceptions?

Tags: entity-framework

My programs use Entity Framework. I want to add new fields to a modelled database table being referenced by these programs, but these programs won't use these new fields (others will use them). It appears that the existing programs start throwing exceptions, even though they don't reference these new fields. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Probably some migration history mismatch, but that's a wild guess without knowing the exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer (or perhaps work-around) is as follows (my experience is only using SQL Server, and using the SSMS to edit the database tables):

If you have a running system and you wish to add new fields to a database table, be sure to add those fields at the "end" of the table's definition, otherwise you will have to rebuild all of the running processes against the new table definition.

Answer (score 0):

My experience in the past has been that Entity Framework can ignore database fields **as long as they are nullable.**  If the new fields are non-nullable, Entity Framework throws exceptions because it can't generate valid insert statements for them.

Answer (score 0):

Just musing, I doubt this is the best solution.

You generate your model against views rather than tables, that will afford you the freedom to modify the underlying tables as required.

Comment: Just curious, did you try this with EF and verify that the problem described goes away? I.e. If I add the field to table and the view (and not at the end) is it still going to throw exceptions? If it does, then it really didn't help, which is what I would guess. I agree that generally speaking programming against views can have advantages, but the question deals with the EF model. If you have verified that this works, I will change my best answer to yours. Thanks.

Comment: So just tried this now as a trivial example, it does work as expected.  Since the view doesn't change, EF doesn't complain.  No idea how this would hold up in a Code-First approach though, we don't use that method.